# Teamcity Stop Build with success

Tags: teamcity

We have a teamcity build, triggered by git, that is doing git integration, sometimes checking into the current branch (it's updating the branch from another source).   This obviously creates another check-in on the same branch, and causes the trigger to see it.

Ideally, I'd block the trigger from seeing that second check-in, but I can't seem to find a way of doing that - as what we are checking in is a conglomeration of changes from other sources.  I know the *last* change is from the build system user, but can't see a way of excluding based on the result of the most recent change.

So I built something in the build script, that correctly ascertains we shouldn't go ahead with this build.   I'm currently just failing - but this isn't actually an error case.  I want to stop the current build without doing any further steps,  but I want the result to be green, and everything to be fine.  Is this possible?   I tried doing the ##teamcity set status, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually "solved" the problem, with a brain-dead but easy hack - I just set a variable "skip", and check it at the start of each subsequent step.   Ugly, but for the moment - it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a VCS trigger rule (5 Build Triggers) with an exclude rule that will not trigger when the build system user commits to your repository. The exclude rule would look something like this:

```
-:user=TeamCityUser
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - but we tried that first - unfortunately, the build is pulling from another repository - so while the merge is under the team city user, there's also a bunch of other changes that aren't - and they seem to be defeating the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out triggers by commit messages. When checking-in from the build agent, always check in using a predefined and specific message. Then you can change the build trigger to not fire when that specific message is part of the commit

Comment: thanks, but same problem - we are doing a pull, so we are getting a large package of changes - with different messages, users etc.  The _most recent_ change is from the system user, but at the trigger level, I don't seem to be able to exclude those other changes if _the most recent of them_ has a particular comment or user.